# How to install Cocos2d (Python) into Python 3.3?

Tags: python-3.3, cocos2d-python

I am trying to use Python 3.3 when developing my next game using [Cocos2d](http://cocos2d.org). I succeeded in installing Pyglet (a Cocos2d dependency) in Python 3.3 but failed to do so for Cocos2d.

The Cocos2d project page lists Python 2.6 as a requirement, but from [this thread in the Cocos2d Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cocos-discuss/Vr1JX6enQiU) it appears that someone has made Cocos2D work with Python 3.3

Previously, using Python3.3 as the default Python interpreter, I use : `pip install cocos2d`. But as it failed, I download manually cocos2d and using a plain `python setup.py install`. Still not working. So I decided to follow the same procedure to install `pyglet` first, it worked. But in trying to convert `cocos2d` using `2to3` it failed with many errors.

Actually, if Python 3.3 is not yet to be supported by Cocos2d.. well, I guess I have to use Python 2.7 then.

But, is there anyone success in installing Cocos2d in Python 3.3 *and* elaborating the process of how to successfully installing it?

Comment: so would a simple "yes/no" be the answer you're looking for, or did you intend to ask something more specific?

Comment: :D okay, rephrase. Got to say, this is my first -1 in SO.

Comment: Your only possible answers to the question in the title are yes - me, yes -so and so or not heard of anybody.  What if anything have _you_ tried?

Comment: Okay, rephrase the question

Comment: where does it appear that cocos2D was made to work with Python 3.x?

Comment: I just answer my own question

Comment: And, it appears after almost two years, this question is answered justly by @Martelmungo. I appreciate it a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cocos2d now supports 3.4
Download Tortoisehg -- http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/download/
Install, open it and go to "View" and click "Show Console"
-- At the bottom of the TortoiseHg window there will be a console, paste in `

```
easy_install cocos2d
```

YOU need:  Pyglet 1.2, "Six", libraries as well. I spent 3 hours trying to figure it out, I know this post is old, but this is the only post I could find for my issues, now I know that Answer, hopefully someone will see this. Does not help being a noob to programming, as I experienced first hand.

Comment: This is important! Surely will help anyone that needs to use Cocos2d with Python 3.4. I accepted it as the answer for my question

Answer (score 2):

From [this page](http://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cocos-discuss/Vr1JX6enQiU), they already answer it, "Current cocos does not support python 3. The next release probably will, but not earlier than april 2014." so, I guess currently it's not possible. I am working with Python 2.7 now.

Answer (score 0):

pip3 install cocos2d. pip is for python version 2.

Answer (score 0):

This became a problem again, not sure why, or if I did a bad thing.

Download the source distribution,
extract *.gz,
extract *.tar,
open setup.py with an editor

line 34 (somewhere in that area) "f = open('README.rst','rU')"

Change the open mode, (the second argument in this open function) "rU" to, "r"

I think this tells it to read it as ascii instead of utf-8... it just doesn't comeback with an error, and I can use cocos in my IDE.

save

open the path in command

C:...\cocos2d-0.6.9>python setup.py install